# How to use a background context with SwiftData? Looking for a CoreData automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent equivalent

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm messing around with refactoring my model layer with SwiftData. I've got my model working and the container set up and working and now I'd like to start using a background context for CRUD operations.

Here's how I'm setting up my Container:

```
@Observable class OhMyModelController {
    public static var shared = OhMyModelController()
    let modelContainer: ModelContainer
    let workContext: ModelContext
    
    public init() {
        let schema: Schema = Schema([TestModelClass.self])
        let inMemory: Bool = Configuration.mode == .unitTesting ? true : false
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(Configuration.mode.rawValue, inMemory: inMemory, readOnly: false, sharedAppContainerIdentifier: Configuration.appGroupName, cloudKitContainerIdentifier: Configuration.cloudKitContainerIdentifier)
        self.modelContainer = try! ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        self.workContext = ModelContext(self.modelContainer)
    }
}
```

And here's how I add or delete (either using the container's main context in the environment or the workContext I create in the controller):

```
    public func create(_ context: ModelContext?) {
        let contextToUse: ModelContext = context != nil ? context! : workContext
        contextToUse.insert(object: TestModelClass(name: "Test"))
        try? contextToUse.save()
    }
    
    public func delete(_ test: TestModelClass, on context: ModelContext?) {
        let contextToUse: ModelContext = context != nil ? context! : workContext
        contextToUse.delete(test)
        try? contextToUse.save()
    }
```

And here's the view I'm using for testing:

```
struct SwiftDataTest: View {
    @Environment(\.modelController) var modelController: OhMyModelController
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext: ModelContext
    @Query() var tests: [TestModelClass]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(tests) { test in
                    Text(test.name)
                        .onTapGesture(perform: {
                            modelController.delete(test, on: modelContext)
                        })
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                modelController.create(modelContext)
            }, label: {
                Text("Testers will test!")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Inserts and deletes work, both on the @Environment modelContext and the workContext, they're just not keeping each other up to date. Is there an equivalent to automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent for SwiftData? It seems odd to think everything is made to be so easy but then I'm going to have to manually track and merge changes using save notifications?

Comment: Are you thinking background context or child context?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the difference is. I'm trying to do something like: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640581-newbackgroundcontext. That's how I currently do Core Data CRUD with Core Data on a background thread (using automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent to keep them both in sync).

Comment: Random thought. Do you have to create a new instance of `ModelContainer` to create your "work" context? Is there any change if you use the UI environment `ModelContainer` instance instead? By creating 2 different instances of containers, I guess there's no way for SwiftData to infer that your 2 contexts should be related. By reusing the same container instance, SwiftData has an opportunity (whether it actually uses that opportunity is TBD) to relate the 2 contexts.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to swing back and mess with this stuff but I guess I'm a bit fuzzy on the container issue you mentioned. Is there a "default" container that is instantiated without me doing anything?  I'm passing the ModelContainer that I instantiate inside OhMyModelController into the environment using the .container modifier on my WindowGroup at the top level of the app.   What Malhal mentioned as an answer seems logically to be something that should work - I'll update as correct once I can get some time to try it out.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize you are also using your `OhMyModelController.modelContainer` for the environment container. That being said, I see how Malhal answer would allow to fix concurrency (ie use a "background" context) but I'm not sure if it would address the lack of parent-child relationship between the contexts.

Comment: I noticed you do this `context != nil ? context! : workContext` which is what the `??` operator is for: `context ?? workContext`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `@Observable` use `@ModelActor`, and include some async funcs that you can call from `.task`.

From the WWDC23 lounge:

> **@Duncan:** As I understand it, SwiftData model objects are not thread-safe, just like `NSManagedObjects`. Are there any additional mechanisms to make managing this easier for us than it was in traditional Core Data? e.g., compiler warnings before passing an object out of its context?
>
> **@Dave N (Apple):** We have provided
> the `ModelActor` protocol & the `DefaultModelExecutor` to make SwiftData work with Swift Concurrency. Use your ModelContainer to initialize a `ModelContext` in the initializer for your `ModelActor` conforming actor object and use that context to initialize a DefaultModelExecutor. This will allow you to use that context with async functions on your actor.
>
> **@Ben T (Apple):** Swift will enforce sendability requirements

As of Xcode 15 beta 1, `@Query` doesn't update to you won't see your changes until you relaunch the app or revisit the screen.

Comment: Lol weren't we talking about this just a few days ago, I guess `ModelActor` is the new way of doing "work", I havent had time to do through all the videos.

Comment: This answer seems to explain how to manipulate a context in a background thread. But how about the question from the OP which has more to do with how to keep the contexts in sync? I see no reference to the notion of child context in SwiftData. Does that mean we have to merge changes manually, as the OP mentioned?

Comment: I believe that this might be handled by persistent history tracking on the store and therefore it might not be needed to explicitly link those contexts together as that will be done through the container that they use.

Comment: I was wondering if SwiftData ever cleans up the transaction history, or does it just get infinitely large?